# cannot access org.hamcrest.Matcher class file for org.hamcrest.Matcher not found in Eclipse and Rest Assured

Tags: maven, pom.xml, rest-assured, hamcrest

Hi I'm a newbie for rest assured and trying to do it in BDD, For that I have written a script while trying to run , I got below mentioned Error

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/akrishnan/eclipse-workspace/BehavDD/src/Test/behaviourDrivenTest.java:[4,27] package org.hamcrest does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/akrishnan/eclipse-workspace/BehavDD/src/Test/behaviourDrivenTest.java:[5,27] package org.hamcrest does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/akrishnan/eclipse-workspace/BehavDD/src/Test/behaviourDrivenTest.java:[23,63] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method hasSize(int)
  location: class Test.behaviourDrivenTest
[ERROR] /C:/Users/akrishnan/eclipse-workspace/BehavDD/src/Test/behaviourDrivenTest.java:[22,29] cannot access org.hamcrest.Matcher
  class file for org.hamcrest.Matcher not found
[ERROR] /C:/Users/akrishnan/eclipse-workspace/BehavDD/src/Test/behaviourDrivenTest.java:[38,41] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method equalTo(java.lang.String)
  location: class Test.behaviourDrivenTest
[ERROR] /C:/Users/akrishnan/eclipse-workspace/BehavDD/src/Test/behaviourDrivenTest.java:[53,28] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method equalTo(java.lang.String)
  location: class Test.behaviourDrivenTest
[ERROR] /C:/Users/akrishnan/eclipse-workspace/BehavDD/src/Test/behaviourDrivenTest.java:[68,63] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method hasSize(int)
  location: class Test.behaviourDrivenTest
[ERROR] /C:/Users/akrishnan/eclipse-workspace/BehavDD/src/Test/behaviourDrivenTest.java:[80,63] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method hasSize(int)
  location: class Test.behaviourDrivenTest
[ERROR] /C:/Users/akrishnan/eclipse-workspace/BehavDD/src/Test/behaviourDrivenTest.java:[128,73] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method equalTo(java.lang.String)
  location: class Test.behaviourDrivenTest
[ERROR] /C:/Users/akrishnan/eclipse-workspace/BehavDD/src/Test/behaviourDrivenTest.java:[149,63] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method hasSize(int)
  location: class Test.behaviourDrivenTest
[INFO] 10 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

I have added the maven dependencies too

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
```

I dont know what I'm missing here. even I tried to set Build path with external jars, still no use.

Comment: If you remove `hamcrest-all`, do you get the same error? `hamcrest-core` and `hamcrest-library` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to remove the scope because I was also using it out of the scoupe test.